# Derive logistic loss gradient in matrix form

Tags: logistic, matrix, gradient

User Antoni Parellada had a long derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278771/how-is-the-cost-function-from-logistic-regression-derivated) on logistic loss gradient in scalar form. Using the matrix notation, the derivation will be much concise.  Can I have a matrix form derivation on logistic loss? Where how to show the gradient of the logistic loss is

$$
A^\top\left( \text{sigmoid}~(Ax)-b\right)
$$

---

1. For comparison, for linear regression $\text{minimize}~\|Ax-b\|^2$, the gradient is $2A^\top\left(Ax-b\right)$, I have a derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887688/help-me-to-derive-the-derivative-for-ax-btax-b).
2. Related question: [Matrix notation for logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229014/matrix-notation-for-logistic-regression/229076)

Comment: As credited in the linked answer, the credit for the derivation goes to the students' cumulative  notes within the [excellent course by Andrew Ng on ML](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning?utm_source=gg&utm_medium=sem&campaignid=693373197&adgroupid=36745103475&device=c&keyword=%2Bandrew%20%2Bng%20%2Bcourse&matchtype=b&network=g&devicemodel=&adpostion=1t1&creativeid=156061453576&hide_mobile_promo&gclid=CjwKEAjw9MrIBRCr2LPek5-h8U0SJAD3jfhtf52WjvuA2lReqWEeGDn6gjkItE1opdUe-hFCvDiZ0BoChXzw_wcB).

Comment: Why not try translating the scalar-form derivation as a [tag:self-study]? (BTW you should edit the question to explicitly state the loss itself, in your preferred notation, to make it self contained)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my try

$$J(x) = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m} b_iln(h_i) + (1 - b_i)ln(1 - h_i)$$

where $h_i = \sigma(x^Ta_i)$. Let $A = [a_1^T, \dots, a_m^T]^T$. Assuming $ln, \sigma, \frac{1}{\cdot}$ work element-wise on vectors, $\odot$ is element-wise multiplication and $\mathbb{1}$ is a vector of $1$s we have

$$J(x) = -\frac{1}{m}\big[b^Tln(\sigma(Ax)) + (\mathbb{1} - b)^Tln(\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax))\big]$$

Now

$$\frac{\partial J(x)}{\partial x}
= 
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}b^Tln(\sigma(Ax)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mathbb{1} - b)^Tln(\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax))\Big]
\\ = 
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[\frac{\partial ln(\sigma(Ax))}{\partial x}b + \frac{\partial ln(\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax))}{\partial x}(\mathbb{1} - b)\Big]
\\ =
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[\frac{\partial \sigma(Ax)}{\partial x} \big(\frac{1}{\sigma(Ax)}\odot b\big) + \frac{\partial \mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax)}{\partial x}\big(\frac{1}{\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax)}\odot (\mathbb{1} - b)\big)\Big]
\\ =
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x} \big(\sigma(Ax) \odot (\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax)) \odot \frac{1}{\sigma(Ax)}\odot b\big) - \frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x}\big(\sigma(Ax) \odot (\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax)) \odot \frac{1}{\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax)}\odot (\mathbb{1} - b)\big)\Big]
\\ =
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[A^T \big((\mathbb{1} - \sigma(Ax)) \odot b\big) - A^T\big(\sigma(Ax)) \odot  (\mathbb{1} - b)\big)\Big]
\\ =
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[A^T \big(b - \sigma(Ax) \odot b - \sigma(Ax) + \sigma(Ax) \odot b\big)\Big]
\\ =
-\frac{1}{m}\Big[A^T \big(b - \sigma(Ax)\big)\Big]
\\ = \frac{1}{m}\Big[A^T \big(\sigma(Ax) - b\big)\Big]
$$