# About inversing the logistic transformation and get a closed form solution for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

It is well known that for a linear regression problem $y=X\beta+\epsilon$, we have a closed form solution $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$.

Then, it's natural to ask the similar question about logistic regression, which has also been discussed (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81000/calculate-coefficients-in-a-logistic-regression-with-r)).

However, I don't understand it well that what the reason there to forbid us from just inverse the logistic transformation and use the closed form solution for linear regression again.

For example, for a logistic regression problem $<y, X>$, since we model it in such a way:
$$
y = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-X\beta}}
$$
why can't we inverse that function to get $X\beta=\log\dfrac{y}{1-y}=y'$, and simply following the closed form to get $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty'$?

I hope the reason is more than "$1-y$ will be zero for $y=1$" because I believe we can always figure out a way to work around these computation issues.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for @Chaconne's suggestion of this [almost identical question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122103/why-is-glm-different-than-an-lm-with-transformed-variable).

Comment: Does this question help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122103/why-is-glm-different-than-an-lm-with-transformed-variable Basically a GLM specifies a model for a transformation of the mean and a distribution for the responses, rather than directly modeling the responses

Comment: Thanks @Chaconne This is truly helpful. I edited the question with a follow-up.

Comment: related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229014/matrix-notation-for-logistic-regression). and do not know if AdamO's answer to my question help.